# How to check date format in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, so I have a column in a pandas table that I created from a CSV file that I am trying to go through and check to see if each cell is a date. Most of them are but there are a few exceptions that I would like to discard from the column. I am able to use the dateutil tool and the following code taken from another forum to insert a single cell and check if it is a date:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date(string, fuzzy = False):
    try:
        parse(string, fuzzy = fuzzy)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False

print(is_date(df.loc[0, 'Column_Name']))
```

This will return "True" when I run the code. What I want to do is use a try loop to check each cell in the column, and if the value is "False" then to delete that row entirely. Im new to coding and am having trouble with the looping part. I appreciate the help!

Edit:
It is month first then day. I can see now that that was not the best example for the format but it doesn't really matter as all date entries will be in that same format. Some of the cells will be other things like a comment by the user which I want to exclude. But, I was able to find a way to loop through the column and print the datetime formated string if it is a date and pass over non date strings:

```
def is_date(date_str, fuzzy = False):
    try:
        parse(date_str, fuzzy = fuzzy)
        return date_str

    except ValueError:
        pass

i = 0
while i < len(df['Column_Name']):
    date_group = is_date(str(df.loc[i, 'Column_Name']))
    try:
        date_change = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_group, '%m/%d/%y').date()
        print(date_change)
    except:
        pass
    i = i + 1
```

Now I need to write to a new column and if T then write the date and if F exclude from the new column

Comment: So every column of a row is a date? Or just the first column is a date?

Comment: Can you give an example of valid/invalid data? Is there any pattern that could be exploited?

Comment: so, most of the columns are dates but there are a few that are not. An example of a valid input would be "02/02/2020" , which returns "True" and invalid would be anything else, which returns "False".

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding this correctly, all the valid dates are in the `"02/02/2020"` format? Is that day first or month first?

Comment: I edited my original post to answer your question. I wasnt able to put my answer in the code format like I was in the original post so it wasnt easy to read. womp womp

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create another column by applying your function and then drop the rows which returned false

```
df['return_label'] = df['Column_Name'].apply(is_date)

df = df[df['return_label']==True]
```

Comment: `== True` is bad practice for at least two reasons, you can simply use `df[df['return_label']]` here.

Comment: Correct it looks more pythonic your version. Thanks